# Finding a paremetric curve traced out by certain lines around a circle

Tags: calculus, geometry

Sorry for the non-descriptive title: it was a rough choice between 3 lines or less description.

Let $O$ be the origin and the centre of a circle with radius $a$. Let $T$ be a point on the circle so that $OT$ makes an angle $t$ with positive $x$-axis. Let $X$ be the point where the tangent of $T$ hits the $x$-axis. Let $P$ be the point where the horizontal line from $T$ intersects with the vertical line from $X$. I am to find a parametric description of $P$ as $T$ moves around on the circle.

If I have understood the task correctly, it is obvious that $-\pi <t < \pi$. Below is an image describing the situation:

[image]

Now, I first want to describe the $x$-coordinate. I know that $P$'s value of $x$ will always be identical to $X$'s value of $x$, so I suppose anything that leads me to $X$'s $x$-coordinate will do. I know that $a \cos t$ takes me part of the way, but it seems tough to find an expression from there. Thinking in vector-language, maybe $[a \cos t, a \sin t]$ to bring me to the $T$ from the origin. I have a feeling that $O \to T \to X$ is the way to go here, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The angle $OXT$ (oops -- typo: I meant $OTX$) is a right angle. That means that 
$$
\cos(t) = \frac{OT}{OX}
$$
so 
$$
OX = \frac{radius}{\cos(t)}.
$$
I think that's what you needed, yes?

Comment: Assuming that right angle translates directly to Norwegian (90 degrees), $OXP$ would be right, not $OXT$.

Comment: I meant $OTX$; corrected inline above. Thanks!